# Using Profile Manager or OS X Server to distribute apps to a group of Macs

Tags: macos, network, applications, server.app, file-sharing

We have around 100 Macs on our network, soon to all be managed by OS X Server and Profile Manager.

The problem we're facing right now is pushing applications to all of them that are not found in the Mac App Store.

We make use of many third party apps, and to save time it would be useful to have a way of distributing them automatically as they become available.

Can this be done with OS X Server, or is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar setup as you are describing and use Apple's Remote Desktop (ARD) application for tasks like installing and updating apps. 
For apps that are .app files, you can use the "copy" command and move them directly to the /Applications folder (or other location like /Library/Quicktime for codecs as an example).
If the installer is a .pkg file, you can use the "install" command in ARD to have it install properly on the remote machine. 
However, for apps that have their own installer application (I'm looking at you Adobe, and your Flash updates!) you are not able to use ARD to help with this. 
Now, although this is not "automatic", you CAN schedule the time of these installs. This way you can do your updating on off hours. 
I hope this info is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

also you can use ARD on your server and on your desktop/laptop, set the server as the task manager and it will keep a que of all your pushes.

Talk a look at a PackageMaker.app, You can download it from https://developer.apple.com/downloads look for "Auxiliary tools for Xcode"
and you can wrap all your apps into one package to push out, this works for almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

From an addition the OP made directly to the question:

> For those interested we've started using Bittorrent Sync to distribute the non-Mac Store Apps. Means that they can get bits of the apps and it doesn't break the connection when they go offline.